# Docs API sometimes takes long to respond

Tags: google-docs

Anyone know why sometimes the Google Sheets API takes a long time to respond? So long that it sometimes times out in my database (Greater than 80seconds).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=[SHEET-ID]&exportFormat=csv

It just says "Waiting for docs.google.com..." and it can vary from a very quick wait to a very long wait.

My file is very small.

Comment: this is not using any api. Please remove the api tags or modify the code. You are just loading a url and there can be a lot of reasons for the delay including your internet connection.

Comment: It requires oAuth within the header, so surely this qualifies for to be an API question?

Comment: no, that doesnt use oauth. Its not an API call. The api would be this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/  Of course it eventually uses oauth as the browser app loads that url